# Unziping multiple ziped and rename automatically files with same name if needed

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, zip, unzip

I have a bunch of Ziped files in a folder, and i would like to unzip all, ut automatically rename folders or files with the same name, example:

In `ZIP_folder_1.zip` and `ZIP_folder_2.zip` i have one folder called `my_name`, if i unzip all with the command above, the command line will ask if i want rename it, so, if i have 3k folders with the same name, i will go crazy.

I'm trying to use:

```
find . -type f -name "*.zip" -exec unzip {} -d {}.contents/;
```

But i am seeing

```
find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

Other point is: Can i pass a destination folder??

Thanks!!!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument to `-exec` is typically the stuff between the `-exec` and the `\;`

I would first try putting a space between the `{}.contents` and the `\;`  but I didn't test it to see what might be going on

for your other point, it's probably easier to alter the starting point for `find` than meddle with the `-exec` clause.  I suggest something like below, recalling that `$OLDPWD` is the old working directory from prior to the last `cd`  (at least in bash it is, in tsch it is `$owd`)

`cd targetdirectory; find $OLDPWD -type f -name "*.zip" -exec unzip {} -d {}.contents /;`

You could embellish it by adding a `; cd $OLDPWD` at the end to return you to your starting point if you wanted